# how to delete SharePoint Group connected sites using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint, I need to delete a SharePoint group connected sites through PowerShell, but i was facing an error

> This site belongs to a Microsoft 365 group. To delete the site, you must delete the group

[image]

how to delete SharePoint group connected sites using PowerShell?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a Microsoft 365 group, all group resources, including SharePoint site, mailbox conversations, Teams, notebook, and Planner tasks also get deleted. So, to delete a SharePoint group connected site, you must need to delete the Microsoft 365 group first.

Here are four methods to delete a Microsoft 365 group.

1.Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Active teams &groups -> Delete the Microsoft 365 group.

2.Use PNP PowerShell.

```
$AdminSiteURL = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$GroupEmail = "Group@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive
 
$Group = Get-PnPMicrosoft365Group | Where Mail -eq $GroupEmail
 
Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group -Identity $Group.id

Write-host "Group Deleted Successfully!" -f Green
```

3.Use Exchange PowerShell.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowBanner:$False
 
Remove-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Group@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
 
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$False
```

4.Use Azure AD PowerShell.

```
#Parameters
$GroupEmail = "Group@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
 
#Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-Null
 
#Get the Azure AD Group
$Group  = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "Mail eq '$GroupEmail'"
 
If($Group)
{
    $Prompt = Read-Host "Are you sure want to delete the Group (Y/N)?"
    If($Prompt -eq "Y")
    {
        #Delete the Office 365 Group
        Remove-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $Group.ObjectId
        Write-Host "Group Deleted Successfully!" -f Green
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/how-to-delete-office-365-group-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) or [CLI for Microsoft 365](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) to easily delete Microsoft 365 group and SharePoint site associated with it.

**Example**:

Using PnP PowerShell:

```
Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group  -Identity <group-id>
```

Using CLI for Microsoft 365:

```
m365 entra m365group remove --id <group-id>
```

**References**:

1. [Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [m365 entra m365group remove](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/entra/m365group/m365group-remove?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Delete all Microsoft 365 groups and SharePoint sites using PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/aad-delete-m365-groups-and-sharepoint-sites/README.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
4. [Delete all Microsoft 365 groups and SharePoint sites using PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/pnp/script-samples/pull/677/files?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

**Important Note**: Link #3 and #4 given above deletes all M365 groups and SharePoint sites associated with. DO NOT run those scripts as is in your environment. I have provided those links just for reference to see how to use those commands. You will have to run the specific commands for only one site/M365 group.